# C++ - Process per Tcp connection

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I need to create process and pass the connected socket to the newly created process and further operations on the socket will be happened in the new process. I have used the following code. Everything work, but when i try to close the child process after the work done, it throws a access violation at the line,

```
return InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(dest, exch, cmp);
```

in the file "win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp", which is at path "boost\asio\detail\impl"

Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP 1
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Windows.h"
#endif
#include <string>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    cout << "Current Process Id...." << GetCurrentProcessId() << endl;
    cout << "Argument count..." << argc << endl;
    if (3 == argc){
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(15));
        ostringstream ss;
        ss << argv[2];
        if (ss.str() == "CHILD"){
            cout << "Message To child...." << ss.str() << endl;
            try
            {
                SOCKET Sock;
                if (2 < argc){
                    Sock = atoi(argv[1]);   // use Sock
                }
                boost::asio::io_service io_service2;
                tcp::socket s(io_service2);
                s.assign(tcp::v4(), Sock); 
                s.send(boost::asio::buffer("Message to client\r\n"));
                s.close();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (exception &e)
            {
                cerr << e.what() << endl; //"The parameter is incorrect" exception
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int m_nPort = 12345;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), m_nPort));

    cout << "Waiting for connection..." << endl;

    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(socket);
    cout << "connection accepted" << endl;

#ifdef _WIN32
    WSAPROTOCOL_INFO pi;
    WSADuplicateSocket(socket.native(), GetCurrentProcessId(), &pi);
    SOCKET socketDup = WSASocket(pi.iAddressFamily/*AF_INET*/, pi.iSocketType/*SOCK_STREAM*/,
        pi.iProtocol/*IPPROTO_TCP*/, &pi, 0, 0);
#else
    //linux
    int socketDup = dup(socket.native()); // tested on Linux, works!
#endif

    {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        TCHAR argbuf[256];

        memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
        wsprintf(argbuf, _T("Server.exe %d %s"), socketDup, _T("\"CHILD\""));
        if (!CreateProcess(NULL, argbuf, NULL, NULL,
            TRUE, // inherit handles
            0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)){
            fprintf(stderr, "createprocess failed %d\n", GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }        
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    }
    socket.close();
    cin.get();
}
```

I found that error is caused by this `"#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP 1"`

but without this, i cannot duplicate the socket at this line, `s.assign(tcp::v4(), Sock);`

How could i resolve this problem, please help me.

Comment: Sorry I read this as passing it to a thread rather than a process. WSADuplicateSocket is the correct way. Do you close the socket on the parent process when you close on the child as well?

Comment: Why? This is how sockets were programmed in the 1980s. Thees days you would use a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution by.

1.comment the line

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP 1
```

2.Change the socket into a shared pointer.
 -thank you @Samer Tufail for the shared pointer suggestion

My working code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Windows.h"
#endif
#include <string>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    cout << "Current Process Id...." << GetCurrentProcessId() << endl;
    cout << "Argument count..." << argc << endl;
    if (3 == argc){
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(15));
        ostringstream ss;
        ss << argv[2];
        if (ss.str() == "CHILD"){
            cout << "Message To child...." << ss.str() << endl;
            try
            {
                SOCKET Sock;
                if (2 < argc){
                    Sock = atoi(argv[1]);   // use Sock
                }
                boost::asio::io_service io_service2;
                tcp::socket s(io_service2);
                io_service2.run();
                s.assign(tcp::v4(), Sock); 
                s.send(boost::asio::buffer("Message to client\r\n"));
                s.close();
                return 0;
            }
            catch (exception &e)
            {
                cerr << e.what() << endl; 
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int m_nPort = 12345;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), m_nPort));

    cout << "Waiting for connection..." << endl;

    boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket(new tcp::socket(io_service));
    acceptor.accept(*socket);
    cout << "connection accepted" << endl;

#ifdef _WIN32
    WSAPROTOCOL_INFO pi;
    WSADuplicateSocket(socket->native(), GetCurrentProcessId(), &pi);
    SOCKET socketDup = WSASocket(pi.iAddressFamily/*AF_INET*/, pi.iSocketType/*SOCK_STREAM*/,
        pi.iProtocol/*IPPROTO_TCP*/, &pi, 0, 0);
#else
    //linux
    int socketDup = dup(socket.native()); // tested on Linux, works!
#endif

    {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        TCHAR argbuf[256];

        memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
        wsprintf(argbuf, _T("Server.exe %d %s"), socketDup, _T("\"CHILD\""));
        if (!CreateProcess(NULL, argbuf, NULL, NULL,
            TRUE, // inherit handles
            0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)){
            fprintf(stderr, "createprocess failed %d\n", GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }        
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood this as copying copying a socket from a 'thread' rather than  a 'process' poor eyesight. WSADuplicateSocket function is correct. However the caveat is the underlying socket will remain open until all descriptors for this socket are deallocated including the parent. [WSADuplicate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741565(VS.85).aspx)

Directly from MSDN:

> A process can call closesocket on a duplicated socket and the
>   descriptor will become deallocated. The underlying socket, however,
>   will remain open until closesocket is called by the last remaining
>   descriptor.

Comment: How could i use this socket in created child process.

Comment: You need to call close on the parent as well, see the MSDN description above.